# Script to fill informations from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script

i need help by creating a script since im a very beginner of scripting.
In this Google Sheet i want to add a script that allows me to move stuff from once page (Order tab) to another page (Overview tab). i want to fill the Orders with all the information which is required.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJALCg9ZkbOHZdK6QuBYsEDSDiHuIbsUmZcD7_YVr3U/edit?usp=sharing

it should be something like:
check column H in Orders tab, if a cell matchs "queue" copy customer name, boss and note as well as the advertiser to the front page (Overview) in the first "free" column so one in which no customer is filled in.

I know how to copy stuff but not how to loop over all the rows to check the state. After the information is copied to front page it should get deleted in Orders tab.

I really hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Most Google Apps functions of this nature begin with something like this:

```
function getOrders(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Orders');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=3;i<vA.length;i++){
    var column1Value=vA[i][0];
    var column2Value=vA[i][1];
    //You can loop through all of the orders data this way and copy the data that you want from each column to the appropriate place on overview
```

You should learn Javascript.  Here's an online [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Also give the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) several reads.

In general this site is dedicated to programmers helping programmers so if you want to maximize your chances to get help, always provide a copy of code that you tried yourself.  We would prefer helping those that are trying to learn on their own.  If on the other hand you would like someone to write this code for you the you might take a look at the Google+ Group "Google Apps Script".